# LSTM to classify long time series sequences

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to train LSTM model to classify long time series sequences with 700 time steps.

**Sample time series belonging to class 1**

[image]

**Sample time series belonging to class 2**

[image]

**Model**

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(700,1), return_sequences=False))  
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(xtrain, y,
              batch_size = 10,
                epochs=20,
              validation_split = 0.2, shuffle= True)
```

The training loss remains constant and validation loss increases since the first epoch. Any ideas on the issue here?

I tried adding convolutional layers with the LSTM layer. This very well improved model accuracy but test loss and accuracy fluctuates very drastically.

[image]

**New model Architecture**

```
def generate_model():

ip = Input(shape=(700,1))
x = LSTM(8)(ip)
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
y = Permute((2, 1))(ip)
y = Conv1D(128, 8, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 5, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = Conv1D(128, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(y)
x = concatenate([x, y])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(ip, out)
model.summary()
return model

model = generate_model()
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history1 = model.fit(xtrain, y,
          batch_size = 10,
            epochs=20,
          validation_split = 0.2, shuffle= True,callbacks=callbacks)
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Some things to check: `y.min() == 0 ?`; `y.max() == 1 ?`; Could you try with `optimizer='adam'`? Have you tried with lower learning rates?

Comment: y.min() == 0 and y_max() == 1.  I am getting the same results with optimizer = 'adam' and with lower learning rates

Comment: Is it constant like "frozen" or "varying too little"?

Comment: Learning rate decay is 1e-6

Comment: I mean the loss.

Comment: loss is varying very little

Comment: Well.... I don't know... normalize the input between -1 and 1; add more `LSTM(return_sequences=true)` layers before the `LSTM(return_sequences=False)`.

Comment: Adding more LSTM layers doesnot improve model performance either. I added convolutional layers instead. Please find my edited question.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?