# Loss and accuracy remains constant in time series classification by LSTM

Tags: python, keras, time-series, classification, lstm

I have a time series data with a classification label of 1 and 0. 
I am using a LSTM model to classify the series by taking 100 consecutive timestamps as input with a single label.

Even after training for many epochs, the loss and accuracy remains constant without even a little variation.
I have tried to change the optimizer(ADAM and SGD), learning rate and number of layers but still the issue remains.

Any idea on why this could be happening?

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064649/lstm-to-classify-long-time-series-sequences) but since I couldn't find any solution, I am posting a question.

[image]

Comment: is you val accuracy much lower than your train accuracy?

Comment: I have pasted an image showing the loss

Comment: how is your balance of the original dataset, out of 100 how many 1 entries do yoiu have?

Comment: The data is highly imbalanced. Around 5 entries out of 100 are 1